# Extract component in formula using bind in ExtJS

Tags: extjs, bind, viewmodel, formula, extjs5

How can I extract the context of the component to which formula is bound? I want to get the context of label1 in the get() of formula1.

I have a view component

```
{
    xtype : 'label',
    name : 'label1'
    bind : {
        text : '{formula1}'
    }
}
```

in view model

```
formula : {
    formula1 : {
        get : function(param){
            //------------------ how to get the name of the label 
            here to which this formula is bound ------
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can bind the name too, ao it will be part of the viewModel, like: `bind: { text: '{formula1}', name: '{label1}'}`

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically, you could use ComponentQuery and find the component you need but I advice **strongly against** this approach. Much better is to bind also `name`. Then you can use `this.getName()` to access value 'label1'.

Comment: Wouldn't using `bind: {text : "{formula1}", name:"{name}"}` run you into the same problem, i.e. once you get into the ViewModel's `name` formula, you don't know which name to return for `label1`? Could you elaborate more, please?